# How is Hashem similar to Mi Yodeya

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We have a famous song called Echad Mi Yodeya and a famous prayer "Hashem Echad".

From here we have a Hekesh of Hashem to Mi Yodeya.

What do we learn from this Hekesh?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Forget about famous prayer, what about the answer to Echad Mi Yodeya? "Echad Elokeinu Shebashamayim Uva'aretz."

Comment: that is Elokeinu, the other is Hashem.. Different aspects of the name

Answer (score 9):

You only quoted part of the prayer. The entire relevant part is:

> ה׳ אחד ושמו אחד לשם ולתפארת ולתהלה
>
> Hashem is one and there's one [schmo](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schmo), for reputation, badges, and glory.

The connection to Mi Yodeya should now be clear.

Comment: Isn't it [four thousand schmos](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I was deliberately avoiding naming the user I thought the prayer was referring to.

Comment: You mean https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/208/joe-shmoe?